# c++ pointers to rows in dynamic matrix

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic

I have a dynamic matrix in a class created by allocating memory in this way:

```
int **m;   //this in the member head pointer


void allocate_mem(int ***ptr, unsigned r, unsigned c){
    *ptr = new int *[r];
    (*ptr)[0] = new int[r*c];
    for(unsigned i = 1; i < r; i++)
        (*ptr)[i] = (*ptr)[0] + i*c;
}
```

how can I call the pointers to the rows? I mean, m is the pointer to the array of pointers, *m is the pointer to the first row, but I don't know how to call the pointers to the other row

Comment: ooh three-star programmer ... anyway, try a `std::vector` for the storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*m` is the pointer to the row with index 0 indeed, but `*m` is equivalent to `m[0]`. So for other indexes use `m[index]`